# need to escape # (hash/pound) character in .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, escaping

The question is fairly simple but I was not able to find an answer for hours now.

What I need to do is:

```
RewriteRule ([^#])#(.*) $1\%23$2
```

Which basically means I want to url escape the freaking hash sign which comes to me from an external codepiece.

backslash (`\`) does not work to escape this sign... and please don't suggest using `%23` instead `#` because it does not work as well.

(`%2`3 does not match a `#` because it simply is not `== %23`)

Answer (score 38):

I just got this working for a site following a couple of posts on this forum, I'm using a rewrite rule with NE not escape and R=301 redirect options:

```
RewriteRule ^galleries/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /gallery.html#/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This redirects all *galleries/variable* to */gallery.html#/variable*

Edit: The important part of the rule is NE which instructs the server to parse output without escaping characters. Without this, it will try and escape the # in the rewrite rule which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: please explain instead of just giving an example

Comment: Whilst this answer contains useful information it _does not_ appear to relate to the OP's question as suggested. The OP is attempting to match a `#` in the RewriteRule _pattern_, whereas the above answer is using a `#` (fragment identifier) in the RewriteRule _substitution_. This is quite different.

Comment: @w3dk, the OP states: "I want to url escape the freaking hash sign." You do this with NE.

Comment: @Dave Must admit, looking back at the question it does seem rather ambiguous... it looks like the OP is both trying to match a `#` (hash) in the request _and_ send a hash back in the response. The `NE` (aka `NOESCAPE`) flag only helps with the later (although it doesn't _escape_ anything - which is what you correctly state in your answer). The _accepted_ answer deals with the former (hash in the request) - which will be the show stopper if the hash is not already URL encoded in the request.

Answer (score 13):

The hash part of a URL is not available for rewriting. When a web browser sends a URL request to a web server it sends everything up to the hash sign. The hash is only available on the client (e.g. JavaScript code can see it).

Comment: this is not a way to escape #, but apparently in my case it does not matter. so i'm gonno go ahead and set this one as accepted. thanks

Comment: While it is true that the part after the # will not be available in the request URL, you can have it as part of the redirect URL. You just have to escape it using the NE option, which is mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @PeterDolberg @Keith The question is about matching a `#` in the pattern. The other answer may help people who find this question from Google, but it's not a valid answer to this particular question. `NE` is not relevant here, and my answer is not "flat-out wrong".

Comment: John, you are correct. Sorry, I mis-read the question; as you suspected, I was looking for the information in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Search ***Extended Redirection*** in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html . There is a nice solution for your question.

Answer (score -3):

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule  old\.php redirect.php?url=http://example.com/new.php|hash [R=301,QSA,L]
```

redirect.php

```
<?php
    $new_url = str_replace("|", "#", $_GET['url']);
    header("Location: ".$new_url, 301);
    die;
?>
```