# Is it possible to escape hashes `#` in .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, escaping

I have followed the instructions described in this article about [Enabling Rich Social Sharing in Angular](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app#_section-what-we-will-need-), but I have a slightly more complicated URL and I I need to escape a `#` hash symbol.

Here is my rewrite condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule sp/#/tab/event/(\d*)$ ogp/events.php?id=$1 [P]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585019/need-to-escape-hash-pound-character-in-htaccess-rewrite-rule) answer rather confusing, as it's not really clear whether it is possible to escape a `#` or not.

An alternative would be to modify the Angular client to not use `#` hash symbols, but I am currently looking for a solution that does not require to modifying the client.

Comment: `#` and part after hash is not sent to web server.