# URL Rewrite with # parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Want to do a rewrite rule

Original link : `http://www.example.com/centre/#/industry=7`

Rewritten link: `http://www.example.com/centre/any-words-here_7.html`

tried something like bellow but didnt worked

```
RewriteRule ^/centre/(.*)_([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/centre/#/industry=$2 [L]
```

thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to place "#/industry" with some work and add "_(value of industry).html" to result, isn't it ?

Comment: I want hide #/industry= with others dynamic words. the number is the id who will change, .html is to show as simple html page

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585019/need-to-escape-hash-pound-character-in-htaccess-rewrite-rule it's not possible to rewrite sharp (#), because it's available only on client

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo it won't work in the `pattern` of the rewriterule, but the substitution can redirect to a URL containing #. Which is what he's trying to do. He's not trying to match the #. You can also use the `NE` flag to preserve the URL.